# Unlatch a bi-directional latch when power is lost?

Tags: circuit-design, solenoid, electromagnetic

I need to design a feature for a system running on DC power that consists of a bi-directional actuated latch pin that instantaneously engages (extends) and disengages (retracts) via user command. A critical need is that the state of the system shall become disengaged if and whenever power is lost/turned-off. Otherwise, if engaged and not powered, the system will be in a highly vulnerable state.

Currently, I have developed a prototyped with a bi-directional latching solenoid. The solenoid was chosen because there is significant shear stress acting on the solenoid plunger. When extended, both ends of the plunger become rigid with a load acting on the exposed plunger length between. Unfortunately, I did not discover this state of vulnerability without power until midway through my development. So therefore:

1. What circuitry could be integrated into this system to achieve the power-off disengage behavior? (I have limited experience with circuit design so this seems very daunting.)
2. Perhaps a bi-directional latching solenoid isn't suitable for what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: This sounds like a mechanical design problem. It doesn't sound like an electronics problem.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I agree in a way - it is multidisciplinary and can be addressed as either. My thought was to solve the de-latching need with some type of circuit that would auto-disengage the latch. However, it could be that may not exist or be so simple to just add in.

Comment: You should convert it to be driven with a constant signal instead of a pulse. You can do that with a circuit that converts a low-to-high voltage transition into a positive current pulse, and a high-to-low transition into a negative current pulse. That can be done with one or two transistors and a couple passives, I believe.

Comment: An [electromagnet](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JL17S4S/) can hold fast to a flat, metal armature with a much greater ratio of force to current than a cylindrical solenoid actuator can hold. I'm imagining that there is some amount of current that is small enough that the magnet can be energized all day without overheating, but great enough to hold the armature in place, and keep your mechanism "locked." A spring would pull the armature away and "unlock" your mechanism if the power failed. Figuring out the "lock"/"unlock" actions then would be the mechanical part of your problem.

Comment: ...Probably you'd need some kind of a mechanical "reset" when power comes back on because the current needed to _hold_ the armature would be much less than the current needed to actively _pull_ the armature back into the "working"/"locked" position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the schematic.

[image]

At power on, the relay K1 is energised and its 'NC' contact is open.

When the solenoid unlatch coil is energised, the electrolytic capacitor gets charged.

When power fails, the 'NC' contact of K1 closes and unlatches the solenoid.

Comment: the electrolytic capacitor should store enough energy for a reliable unlatch, the resistor should be so small that loading of the capacitor is done in a short time but the resistor must be so large that the loading current peak is not too high. the operating voltage should be somewhat higher than the minimum needed by the unlatch solenoid to shorten the  loading time of the capacitor.

Comment: @Uwe - Hi, I'm with you.  A feasibility check may be carried out should more details be made available. Many thanks.

Comment: @vu2nan could you clarify on the symbols and behavior w.r.t the 4 latch and unlatch switches? I'm having a difficult time visualizing the behavior.

Comment: Hi treked011, The switches marked 'latch' and 'unlatch' are momentary push button switches, each having 1 'NO' and 1 'NC' contact. They are wired as shown to prevent erratic behaviour, that would occur, should only the 'NO' contacts be wired and both be simultaneously actuated.

Comment: @vu2nan thanks. I'm wondering if K1 relay and switch is really necessary? I have the 'NC' state for both latch and unlatch relays wired to unlatch the solenoid. If power fails, then 'NC', or the unlatch behavior, will be automatically set. Therefore, the RC loop would be powering the 'NC' unlatch setting from the relays. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Hi treked011, The two push button switches latch and unlatch the solenoid. No relays are required to latch / unlatch the solenoid. K1 relay is used to sense the power-off condition. Please post a schematic of your proposed solution.